# Load API Data in UICalendarView

Tags: ios, swift, api, calendarview

I have gone through the UICalendarView implementation and it's working fine. I'm getting a list of holiday data and want to populate the UICalendarView to show the user of respective dates for holidays. I want to discriminate the date visually through background color as well. How I can populate the API data in ClaendarView Delegate and load in the UI.

```
    let calendarView = UICalendarView()
    calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    calendarView.calendar = .current
    calendarView.locale = .current
    calendarView.fontDesign = .rounded
    calendarView.delegate = self
    calendarView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    calendarView.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(calendarView)

    let selection = UICalendarSelectionSingleDate(delegate: self)
    calendarView.selectionBehavior = selection

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        calendarView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        calendarView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        calendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
        calendarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor)])



func dateSelection(_ selection: UICalendarSelectionSingleDate, didSelectDate dateComponents: DateComponents?) {
    let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let showDate = dateComponents?.date
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let resultString = inputFormatter.string(from: showDate!)
    print(resultString)
}

func dateSelection(_ selection: UICalendarSelectionSingleDate, canSelectDate dateComponents: DateComponents?) -> Bool {
    print(dateComponents)

    return true
}

func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
    for items in listData {
        print(items.date)

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: items.date ?? "")
        print(date)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: I have "listData" an array of lists of holidays.

Comment: This method is asking for a specific date (through `dateComponents`), do you want a custom decoration? `func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration?` I don't know what's `listData` exactly, but you need to check if in it, you have the current date of `dateComponents`.

Comment: After using UICalenderView above code, it shows me a normal calendar and current date. I want to show my API data in the calendar that is having a date as String in listData array. Those dates should be highlighted with different color schemes and on click of that date, I have to show a popup message.

Comment: Currently you return `nil`, you don't do anything, which I guess why it's not doing anything in that method. You need if listData.contains(where: ???) { customize cell, don't return nil }

Comment: Here is data coming in the response:
    "name": "New Year's Day",
    "country": "SG",
    "type": "public_holiday",
    "date": "1/1/2020"

I want to show this date on the calendar as highlighted and the name of the holiday as a popup message. @Larme

Comment: So you need to convert `"date": "1/1/2020"` into `Date` or `DateComponents`, and compare with the `dateComponents` of the method.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried with that and converted String into Date. But as I pass data to the return value it throws an error message: " Cannot convert return expression of type 'Date?' to return type 'UICalendarView.Decoration?"

Comment: You need to return a Decoration. Read what it is. It can be a custom view, etc.